Charge amplifier for electrometer or alternatives?
I‘ve recently been looking into the measurement of charges beyond the simple illustrative electroscope types which one has possibly seen in school or elsewhere.
Specifically, I am interested in the working principles and further considerations of those „lab-grade“ electrometers like those from Keithly or Keysight, capable of measuring very low amounts of charge.
Question 1: From what I have been reading, their common working principle is based on a charge amplifier circuit (e.g. Charge Amplifier on Wikipedia)?
Question 2: Does this imply that by measuring the charge, the charged object will become discharged? For the „simple“ implementation it is clear to me that this is the case. Would those lab electrometers have the same issue, i.e., one cannot simply repeat the measurement?
Related to the main question: do other electrometer manufacturers (which I admit I haven’t found for lab use) use different measurement principles and circuits?

Google "keithley low level measurements handbook"

Thank you! That’s a very helpful resource.
